# Popularity of Editorial Express

Tags: journals, conference, journal-workflow

Why do many journals and conference organizers use Editorial Express and the related Conference Maker (https://www.editorialexpress.com/)? The tools look like a relic from the 90s. And at least the manuscript submission tool contains a few bugs.

Is it a competitive pricing, an integration with related software, or potential disruptions associated with migrating to alternative platforms?

This question is not meant as a critique or an attack on the Editorial Express brand. I am just surprised whenever I use that tool.

Comment: Maybe a lot of editors and academics are "relics from the 90's". I know I am. Maybe it works.

Comment: @Buffy - I'm not quite sure what decade I'm a relic from, but it predates the 90's...

Comment: I suspect the answer is that it is not actually popular.

Comment: It is very commonly used in economics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [77 journals use Editorial Express](https://editorialexpress.com/e-editor/). Given that there are tens of thousands of scholarly journals, it does not seem to be immensely popular.

Anyway, one [Editorial](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.2737475) justifies the adoption of Editorial Express. It might answer parts of your question:

> We have decided to use Editorial Express, developed by Professor John Rust at the University of Maryland. This software is very cost effective, and allows for much flexibility in how it is used. The software will send automatic reminders to reviewers, automatically save contact information provided by authors and reviewers, save all correspondence and manuscripts, and has many reporting functions. Editorial Express is Web-based, which allows the editors to use the software at any time, in any place. Ideally, this Web-based solution will allow us to coordinate the duties of John Mallinckrodt and myself, and might provide for some significant financial savings.

To examine the argument about cost-effectiveness further: The standard price of Editorial Express is [$2000 per year](https://editorialexpress.com/e-editor/info.cgi), but can even be lower due to its "lowest price guarantee"-scheme. In comparison, one of its competitors, Manuscript Manager, has a graded pricing that may cost [up to $8500 per year](https://manuscriptmanager.com/pricing/). Another one, ScholasticaHQ, offers a "peer review system" that costs [$250 per year in addition to $10 per submitted manuscript](https://scholasticahq.com/pricing) (thus, if you have 200 submissions per year, it adds up to $2250).